# I want to use OpenSSL in the Cooja simulator in the Contiki OS but I'm unable to integrate it

Tags: openssl, contiki, cooja

I have installed OpenSSL which I can check using the command `openssl version`, but when I add header files related to the OpenSSL, let's say for calculating HMAC, I get the error "no such file or directory". If I make a simple C file with the code and run it using the command `gcc test.c -lssl -lcrypto` I get the output. I want to use this library in the `rpl-icmp6.c` file in the `core/net/rpl` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The short answers is that it's not possible to integrate OpenSSL in Contiki. Why? The name OpenSSL comes from "Secure Socket Library", and there are no sockets in Contiki. You cannot use OpenSSL since a core API it's expecting is missing.

You can, however, extract some code from OpenSSL, for example, the implementations of various cryptographic primitives, and integrate them in Contiki as regular C source files. Doing this goes beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Is it possible you can point me towards a resource which can help me to use the digital signature and verify digital signature in Contiki Cooja simulator?